# Github, some images doesn't show

Tags: git, image, svg, github, html

I made a site, which is hosted on gh-pages branch. You can visit site here: https://pacxiu.github.io/RetroPSD/

also link to repo https://github.com/pacxiu/RetroPSD

The problem is that it doesn't show all images. I know that Linux is case-sensitive but why then some images - link for instance background images could be found. Also SVG with icons at the bottom of site. Also first image of Kodak Camera is found, but then I got 404 :/

Answer (score 1):

Your `images` directory is stored in the `RetroPSD` directory and yet you reference them with a relative path which looks for the `images` directory at your root.

E.g. What your HTML says (on the homepage):

```
../images/icons/tv.svg
```

Which becomes (after resolution):

```
https://pacxiu.github.io/images/icons/tv.svg
```

The `..` refers to the parent directory.

What you want is:

```
images/icons/tv.svg
```

or better yet make it relative from the root (so it works on all pages):

```
/RetroPSD/images/icons/tv.svg
```

Answer (score 0):

In index.html all of your img src's have `'../images/[name of image]'`, the .. at the start means move up a directory, but your images folder is in the same folder as the index.html file. The site is looking for an images folder in the wrong place because of the `../`, to fix this just need to replace the `../images` with `images/`.